# How to assign a variable of repeated character using the length of another variable in AWK?

Tags: string, bash, awk

I want to have a variable with repeated `.` or `space` of length of the variable `pat`, I had tried the following command

```
awk -v pat="AAGCTT" -v rep=$("printf '.%.0s' length(pat)")
awk -v pat="AAGCTT" -v rep=$("printf '.%.0s' {1..length(pat)}")

some actions using both pat & rep as variable
```

But the following error is outputted

```
printf '.%.0s' {1..length(pat)}: command not found
```

How can I generate the variable that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
var=$(awk -v pat="AAGCTT" 'BEGIN { printf "%*s", length(pat), "" }')
echo "${#var}"
```

```
6
```

Instead of `printf`, you could just do `gsub` and reuse `rep`:

```
var=$(awk -v pat="AAGCTT" -v rep="." 'BEGIN {
gsub(/./, rep, pat); print pat}')
```

Comment: I want to reuse the `rep` & `pat` variable in the following action for awk, so this may not be a good solution for me

Comment: We can use `rep` but your syntax of `"printf '.%.0s' length(pat)"` is wrong because it is trying to execute `printf` in `shell` with bad shell syntax.

Comment: See my updated answer on how to make use of `rep` argument.

Comment: although this is correct, I have to change the `pat` twice if needed, which make it more complicated, thanks anyway

Comment: @hey0god what are you talking about? And if this doesn't do what you want then why did you accept it as the answer thereby discouraging other people from posting answers that might do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way for assigning `rep` with repeating character `X` of `length(pat)`

```
awk -v pat="AAGCTT" -v rep="X" 'BEGIN {var = pat;gsub(/./,rep,var);} {
    some action
}'
```

where

```
pat = "AAGCTT"
rep = "X"
var = "XXXXXX"
```

Comment: How is that any more elegant than what @anubhava showed you in his answer? Your script is just a minor tweak to the second script he provided such that you're now hard-coding the replacement character.

Comment: I just edited my own answer, which remove the hard-code, function the same as @anubhava answer, but the `pat` variable only requires to be changed once

Comment: I think you must misunderstand what @anubhavas scripts are doing as he's changing the `pat` variable at all in the first script and only once in the 2nd one. The only difference in yours is you've introduced an unnecessary awk variable named `var`.